# How to set Client_Encoding

Tags: postgresql, character-encoding

I'm using `NodeJS` to get some data from a `PostgreSQL` database and render it on the web. When I make a query on `SQL Shell(psql)` everything looks fine but when I console.log that same data from `NodeJS`, all the special characters are replaced with gibberish. 
The encoding for this database is

```
- Encoding: UTF8
- Collation: French_France.1252
- Ctype: French_France.1252
```

I tried to set Client_Encoding to `UTF8` but when I reconnect to the database I find out that it is still not set.
Also I get this warning each time I connect to the database (Just in case it may cause smth)

```
WARNING: Console code page (850) differs from Windows code page (1252)
     8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
     page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
```

My OS is `Windows 8` and `PostgreSQL` version is `10.x`.

Comment: Which PostgreSQL driver/connector are you using ? Did you tried "chcp 1252" command before starting your node script ?

Comment: I did! Doesn't work either...

Comment: Which PostgreSQL driver/connector are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

After a long search I have found a solution that I want to share now.

Change your ODBC DSN connection string to include this: `ConnSettings=SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8';`